# Should Keyboard Listeners be removed in componentWillMount?

Tags: react-native, keyboard, react-navigation

**Problem:**
I have an app with 2 screens in Stack-Navigator, both of which have TextInputs. Each screen adds keyboard listeners in the componentWillMount as follow:

```
  this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
  this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
```

Therefore, if I trigger the Keyboard on one screen in the stack, it will get triggered on another one, meaning that the keyboardWillShow / keyboardWillHide are being accessed on both screens (because componentWillUnmount is not called on the screen after the user has navigated from them to the next page in the stack.

**Questions:**
1. Is it a good idea to keep it this way in terms of performance orientation or better add `Keyboard.removeAllListeners()` right before adding new listeners in the `componentWillMount` of each screen (as shown below)? I have managed to add `Keyboard.dismiss()` to the block of code to be run when navigating back from the second screen in the stack so **I do not have unexpected behavior**.

```
 // componentWillMount of both screens in the stack
 Keyboard.removeAllListeners();
 this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
 this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
```

2. Am I doing something wrong?